# macOS - scanned document not showing properly in Notes.app

Tags: macos, iphone, notes.app, scanning

I was on macOS 12.1 and iOS 15.2, and scanned a document in Notes on my iPhone and it showed up on my Mac like this:
[image]

The scanned doc wasn't showing a preview and didn't open when I double clicked on it on the Mac, but it was showing properly on the phone.

I tried to restart Notes.app and modifying the note's content to force a sync, but neither of them worked.

This actually happened quite often on macOS Big Sur, is there a way to address this issue (a workaround) before Apple fixes it?